# db4o: LINQ equivalent of SODA query?

Tags: linq, db4o, soda

For db4o, I'm trying to find the LINQ code that generates the following SODA:

```
    var query = db4o.db.Query();
    query.Descend("Symbol");        
    query.Descend("_symbolGlobal").Constrain("APPLE");
    query.Descend("_date"); // Add a date constraint here.
    IObjectSet result = query.Execute();
```

All the SODA does is drop down the tree to an end node. For example, if you wanted to select "APPLE" for date "2010-10-18", it would return "Apples on Thursday".

Data structure:

```
Root ----Symbol (APPLE)                
   |          |------Day 1: Date: 2010-10-18, string "Apples on Thursday"
   |          |------Day 2: Date: 2010-10-19, string "Apples on Friday"
   |
   |
   |-----Symbol (PEAR)               
              |------Day 1: Date: 2010-10-18, string "Pears on Thursday"
              |------Day 2: Date: 2010-10-19, string "Pears on Friday"
```

Here is my first attempt, which doesn't work as its getting the cross product (i.e. its looking at every possible combination). I can't use a join, as db4o is an object database and you don't have access to the ID for each object, like in a RDBMS.

```
    var stringForDayAndSymbol = from s in db4o.db.Query<Symbol>(a => a.SymbolGlobal == "APPLE")
                          from t in db4o.db.Query<Date>(b => b.Date == new DateTime(2010, 10, 20))
                          select new
                          {
                            s.SymbolGlobal,
                            t.Date,
                            t.Meta
                          };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really directly want to descent into "Symbol" with `query.Descend("Symbol");`? I guess that you want to constrain for the type 'Symbol'. I just assume that you meant this:

```
var query = db4o.db.Query();
query.Constrain(typeof(Symbol));        
query.Descend("_symbolGlobal").Constrain("APPLE");
query.Descend("_date"); // Add a date constraint here.
IObjectSet result = query.Execute();
```

Not 100% sure, but should be something like this:

```
// I assume here that the field _symbolGlobal is accessable with the property SymbolGlobal
// and the field _date is accessable with the property Date
var result = from Symbol s in db4o.db
            where s.SymbolGlobal == "APPLE"  
            select s.Date;
```

Comment: I've marked this answer as correct, however, if you are trying to descend into a collection of objects, such as anything instantiated with an IList, then it won't work (collections seem to be invisible to SODA).

Comment: Hmm, i think the 'contains'-operation on collections should also work with LINQ. Like s.SymbolGlobal.Contains("Apple").